# Using Gatsby JS and markdown MDX, how can I render HTML5 animations in MDX?

Tags: javascript, html, gatsby, mdxjs

Setting up a personal blog with Gatsby JS, using the excellent [Chronoblog theme](https://github.com/Chronoblog/gatsby-theme-chronoblog). I need to embed small clips of HTLM5 animations, inside a markdown MDX document.

The animations-presentations are created from [Google WEB Designer](https://webdesigner.withgoogle.com/) and are exported locally as assets; js and html files.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you want a helpful answer you need to tell us what have you tried and where did you get stuck. Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't had an error but looking for a direction, should I use a plugin ? Which one? Other ideas...

From what I found, there is basically 2 options to create animated presentation in MDX documents;  use an app that creates html5 containers (Google Web designer, Tumult Hype...)  and find a way to present them into an MDX document or, to use third party apps were you only have to put an iframe in the page.

After trying many options, I reverted to use iframes for the simplicity. Tried many apps like Visme, Greensock and others, to finally go with Reveal.js-Slides.com.

First post here, got a "-1" and answered my own question... Hum.

Thanks.

François